# Printing XeLaTeX-compiled PDF containing OTF fonts produces corrupted output

Tags: xetex, fontspec, printing

I am compiling a PDF document containing an OTF font using XeLaTeX.

I'm using the `fontspec` package and the `\setsansfont{}` command to define this OTF font as my sans serif default. The following code reproduces the error:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\title{Document Title}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{MarkPro-Bold.otf}

\begin{document}

\maketitle % This will be rendered in the OTF sans-serif font

\end{document}
```

The output looks fine on screen, but printing the document creates a jumbled mess. The properties dialogue in Acrobat shows that the font is embedded in the file. The problem has been reproduced in the Chrome PDF viewer, Preview.app (Mac OS), and Adobe Acrobat.

Note that all text that is set in Computer Modern prints just fine, so I'm sure it's related to the fact that I'm using the custom font using an OTF file.

What could cause the problem and how can it be fixed?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Below the title as it looks on screen...

[image: Title as it looks on screen]

And as it looks in print...

[image: Title as it looks in print]

Comment: The problem is possibly with your custom font. Unfortunately without having the font it would be hard to reproduce. If you can upload either the font or a minimal PDF which contains the issue, more people may be able to help you. (Also, have you tried this with different printers, or different software (say OS) for printing?)

Comment: Try also with lualatex -- if it has problems too, the log-file and the lua-file will perhaps give more info.